# What does the set $C_0 = \{ f \in C(\Omega) : spt(f) \text{ is compact subset of } \Omega \} $ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

What does the set $C_0 = \{ f \in C(\Omega) : spt(f) \text{ is compact subset of } \Omega \} $ mean?

Why is $spt( \cdot)$ there?

Comment: "spt" is for support.  Is that a familiar term?

Comment: Why is your question making it seem like there's some hidden meaning...

Comment: @Randall I thought it meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spt_function

Comment: The support of $f$ is the closure of the set $\{f(x) \ne 0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$\operatorname{spt}(f)$" is the **support** of $f$: the closure of the set of values on which the function isn't zero. Saying "$\operatorname{spt}(f)$ is compact" should be thought of as saying (in part) "$f$ is 'rarely' nonzero."

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if spt$(f)$ was intended to mean the **closure** of the set of values on which the function $f$ isn't zero.  That has a better chance of being compact.  The OP should look for the intended meaning in the document where the quoted definition of $C_0$ appears.

Comment: No, continuity implies that $\{x:f(x)\neq0\}$ is open, because it's the inverse image of the open set $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ (or $\mathbb C-\{0\}$ if $f$ is complex-valued).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Wow, that was not my finest moment. Fixed!